# PostGIS SQL: Internal buffer of unioned polygons

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a polygon layer containing titles which are grouped by a property ID (i.e. there may be one or more title polygon per property)

I need to generate an internal buffer of those unioned titles/of the property but can't quite get it working- with the code below, the internal buffer *is* generated but for all titles individually (i.e. there are buffers on the internal divisions)

How can I apply a union to the 'titles' before the difference?

Alternatively, is there a better way of generating an internal buffer of unioned/merged polygons grouped by an attribute?

```
SELECT
  row_number() OVER () AS fid,
  g.geom::geometry(Polygon,2193) AS geom,
  g.forest_id
FROM (
  SELECT
    (ST_Dump(
       ST_Union(
         ST_Difference(
           titles.geom,
           ST_Buffer(titles.geom, - 10::double precision)
         )
       )
    )).geom AS geom,
    titles.forest_id
  FROM public.titles
  GROUP BY titles.forest_id) g;
```

[image: example of problem]

Comment: How about moving the ST_Union inside the call to ST_Buffer?

Comment: I have tried but I can't get the syntax correct :( (I find the pgadmin syntax error messages rather unhelpful as they refer to line numbers which aren't even in the query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the residue area of a subtraction of unioned `titles.geom` and their negative buffer based on common `titles.forest_id`, run:

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS fid,
  u.forest_id,
  dmp.path[1] AS seq,
  dmp.geom
FROM (
  SELECT
    forest_id,
    ST_Union(geom) AS geom
  FROM
    titles
  GROUP BY
    1
) AS u,
  LATERAL ST_Dump(
    ST_Difference(
      u.geom,
      ST_Buffer(u.geom, -10)
    )
  ) AS dmp
;
```

---

**Update:**

If your geometric conditions are simple enough, it is more performant to create a side-specific buffer along the `ST_Boundary` of the unioned geometries; see the example section in the [docs for `ST_Buffer`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html).

Since I'm at it, here's a possible alternative to the above; on larger datasets, this should definitely be a lot faster.

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS fid,
  u.forest_id,
  buf AS geom
FROM (
  SELECT
    forest_id,
    ST_Union(geom) AS geom
  FROM
    titles
  GROUP BY
    1
) AS u,
  LATERAL ST_Buffer(
    ST_Boundary(u.geom),
    10,
    'side=right'
  ) AS buf
;
```

Note that you need to make sure all your *Polygons* are oriented the same (i.e. via `ST_ForceRHR`, either on-the-fly or as an `UPDATE` to the table) for the `side=left|right` parameter working as expected.

Comment: That query (although it does get rejigged after saving in pgadmin) returns a geometry-less table?

Comment: @Tim ah yes, the arguments passed to `ST_DIfference` were in the wrong order - fixed that in the query above.

Comment: Brilliant- thank you, that's exactly what I was after.